# How to vlookup different values having same IDs within different groups

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to figure out how to vlookup a value that has same name between different groups.
I am trying to figure out how to vlookup a value that has same name between different groups.
Given tables below:

[image]

What I would like to do is to fill Table 2 with the x values in Table 1, assuring that the subgroups actually belong to the right group.

Note that: Subgroups names are fixed, Group names change, number of subgroups within the groups may differ.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, your groups are in column A and values in column B.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($E$2,INDIRECT("A" &MATCH($D$2,A:A,0)+1&":A1048576"),0)+MATCH($D$2,A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Nevertheless,I would need something that would work on a column. I.e imagin to have a dubplicate of column A, in column H, but without values..how would u make the formula work when scrolling down?

Comment: It's not really clear what you'd like to see. Do you have a screenshot of it?

Comment: Have edited the question. Hope is clearer now. thanks a lot